# PHP about some small mistake I'm afraid

Tags: php

I was making an active/unactive system for my navbar. I just did it with a if/else because my PHP skills aren't that good. But now I have 2 rules of the PHP, but it gives me an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\De Campagne\includes\header.php on line 36

```
<li class="<?php if($page == home){echo 'nav-active'} else{ echo 'nav-unactive'};?>"></li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>  //Line 36
<li class="<?php if($page == leveringen){echo 'nav-active'} else{ echo 'nav-unactive'};?>"><a href="leveringen.php">Leveringen</a></li>  //Line 37
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: as long as `home` is not a constant, you need to escape it `'home'`

Comment: As other answers have shown, the error is actually telling you what's wrong. In this case, it said it was expecting a comma or a semicolon somewhere, but instead found a closed curly bracket. So that means you just haven't properly included a semicolon inside your IF statement.

Comment: styling tip: try to give the general idea of your question in the question title, it will help others to find your question or decide if they actually look into it if they see the question in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Statements must end with a semicolon ;

Add them after each statement to indicate that the statement is finished. e.g.

```
echo 'nav-active';
```

You should, however, not be adding a semicolon after the else statement since the curly braces take care of it.

### Use quotations around strings for comparison

Add " or ' around *home* and *leveringen* to indicate that you're comparing string values -- unless those are really constants that you've already defined somewhere else.

### This should work for you:

```
<li class="<?php if($page == "home"){echo 'nav-active';} else{ echo 'nav-unactive';}?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="<?php if($page == "leveringen"){echo 'nav-active';} else{ echo 'nav-unactive';}?>"><a href="leveringen.php">Leveringen</a></li>
```

[A tweeked demo demonstrating how the links should look like with this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be68acdecc7984701b4ecb9c58e03a8ee0006eec) (Press execute code)

**Offtopic:**

Consider the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) as an alternative to if-else statements.

### Edit:

Remember to remove that extra `</li>` in the earlier case which occurs too early.

Comment: Hey guys, I just can't get it done. Is there nobody here who could write a code that gives an active class to an a tag, when the defined page is visited. Would really appreciate it.

Comment: @CaspervanSligtenhorst Woops there was a typo in the code, try it again.

Comment: @CaspervanSligtenhorst Also, you have one too many `</li>` in the home link.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(You forgot the semicolons! Also if `home` and `leveringen` isn't a constant you have to put quotes around them)

```
<li class="<?php if($page == home){echo 'nav-active';} else{ echo 'nav-unactive';} ?>"></li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="<?php if($page == leveringen){echo 'nav-active';} else{ echo 'nav-unactive';}?>"><a href="leveringen.php">Leveringen</a></li>
```

And if you want to use a ternary operator use this:

```
<li class="<?= (($page == home) ? "nav-active" : "nav-unactive") ?>"></li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="<?= (($page == leveringen) ?"nav-active" : "nav-unactive") ?>"><a href="leveringen.php">Leveringen</a></li>
```

Comment: Aigh, it worked with the ternary operator. but now it's doesn't select the <a> tags. If I remove the <a> tags, and put Home and Leveringen directly between the <li> tags, then it works. But I need them to be in the <a> tags.

Comment: @CaspervanSligtenhorst What do you mean? I don't really get what you want to say.

Comment: When I put it like    <li class="<?= (($page == home) ? "nav-active" : "nav-unactive") ?>"></li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li> It doesn't work, because the css cant select the a. But when I remove the a tag, and put Home between the li tags, it works, and it selects the css styling. I'm sorry, but I don't no how to explain it easier...

Answer (score 0):

You missed the semicolon after echo and there is no need of ; after else

```
<li class="<?php if($page == home){echo 'nav-active';} else{ echo 'nav-unactive';} ?>"></li>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
 </li>
<li class="<?php if($page == leveringen){echo 'nav-active';} else{ echo 'nav-unactive';}?>">
    <a href="leveringen.php">Leveringen</a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend,

You are missing semicolon after echoing inside IF statement:

```
line 36: <li class="<?php if($page == home){echo 'nav-active';} else{ echo 'nav-unactive'};?>"></li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
line: 37 <li class="<?php if($page == leveringen){echo 'nav-active';} else{ echo 'nav-unactive'};?>"><a href="leveringen.php">Leveringen</a></li>
```

You need to read syntax error you've showed. Missing ';'.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply implement it as like :

```
<li class="<?php echo (($page == 'home') ? 'nav-active' : 'nav-unactive');?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: That one doesn't do anything, but it could be possible that I gave the page a variable on the wrong way. I gave index.php the variable on the following way: <?php $page = 'home'; ?>  Is that correct?

Comment: this complete statement is correct `<?php echo (($page == 'home') ? 'nav-active' : 'nav-unactive');?>` this is the ternary operator provided by PHP for shorthand if else conditons.

Answer (score 0):

it's finally done. Thank you all for your help. I fixed it with a ternary operator, and correct CSS asignment.